# Splitting a string into an array, unwanted element in the array (it seems)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My code splits just fine, but when I iterate through and cout each element, the last cout is always the original string with no modification.

For example:

```
SplitRowIntoArray("1,2,3");
```

Will output: `1 2 3  1,2,3`

```
void SplitRowIntoArray(std::string row){

    std::string str = row;
    std::string strWords[24];
    short counter = 0;

    for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(str[i] == ','){
            counter++;
        }
        else
        strWords[counter] += str[i];

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(strWords); i++){
        std::cout << strWords[i] << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(strWords)` ==> `counter` . Learn what [`sizeof` really does **here**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Comment: use std::vector for strWords

Comment: @molbdnilo "and nothing more." it will ouput "1\n2\n3\n" and then `sizeof(std::string[24]) - 3` times garbage.

Answer (score -1):

Use Locales, `std::stringstream` and `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


struct comma_is_space : std::ctype<char>
{
    colon_is_space()
    : std::ctype<char>(get_table())
    {}

    static mask const* get_table()
    {
        static mask rc[table_size];
        rc[',']  = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return rc;
    }
};

void SplitRowIntoArray(std::string row)
{
    std::stringstream ss{ row };
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new comma_is_space));

    std::vector<std::string> words{
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ss},
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}
    };

    for (auto const & word : words)
        std::cout << word << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    SplitRowIntoArray("1,2,3");
}
```

Comment: I think the OP needs more basic info rather than a "here's your code" answer

Comment: @HerrJoebob I think the OP needs so way much more basic info than in a SO answer can be given so he should read a good(tm) book on C++.